# Django - Execute Celery task with options but no function arguments

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Celery for the first time. Looking at the documentation, it seems like I've tried everything to properly execute the task using apply_async. I'm calling the task from a signal method so it's in signals.py.

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from games.models import Game
from contacts.models import Contact
from msgs.models import SMS
from msgs.tasks import sendSMS_Scheduled


@receiver(post_save, sender=Game)
def createSMS(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:

        contacts = Contact.objects.all()
        body = SMS.defaultMessageBuilder(
            location=instance.location,
            time=instance.schedStart
        )
        eta = instance.schedStart - timedelta(hours=7)
        expire = instance.schedStart
        result = sendSMS_Scheduled.apply_async(eta=eta, expires=expire)
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from SMSerSite.celery import app
from contacts.models import Contact

from .models import SMS

@shared_task(name='SMSerSite.msgs.tasks.sendSMS', bind=True)
def sendSMS_Scheduled():

    messages = self.request.sms_set.all()

    SMS.sendSMS(messages)
```

When the code runs, I get an error: `sendSMS_Scheduled() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. I've tried various ways of writing the line where I call the task using apply_async but nothing works. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `bind=True` keyword argument, your task gets a reference to itself, so change your method signature to:

`def sendSMS_Scheduled(self):`

As a side note, keep in mind that `self` in this context is the actual celery task. You have a line `self.request.sms_set.all()` which makes me think you are expecting `self` to be something django specific.

Comment: That makes sense and fixed the issue.

Regarding the `self.request.sms_set.all()`: I intend for the task result object to be a foreign key value on all of the SMS objects. But that's a whole other issue I haven't looked at much yet.

Comment: Got it. What I generally do with celery tasks that operate on django models is pass the primary keys of the objects it needs to operate on (as opposed to actual objects). This allows you to avoid pickle serialization. But as you say, that's a whole other issue, and we can address it when you get to that point.

Comment: I've considered that. That's helpful guidance. I'll try implementing it that way instead.